# GCC function multiversioning and namespaces

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following code snippet which uses GCC's function multiversioning.

```
//ver.h
#include<string>
namespace nt {
__attribute__ ((target ("default"))) std::string version();
__attribute__ ((target ("sse2")))    std::string version();
__attribute__ ((target ("ssse3")))   std::string version();
__attribute__ ((target ("sse4")))    std::string version();
}

//ver.cpp   
#include "ver.h"
using namespace nt;    
__attribute__ ((target ("default"))) std::string nt::version() { return "default"; } 
__attribute__ ((target ("sse2")))    std::string nt::version() { return "sse2";    } 
__attribute__ ((target ("ssse3")))   std::string nt::version() { return "ssse3";   } 
__attribute__ ((target ("sse4")))    std::string nt::version() { return "sse4";    }
```

The code works fine if the functions are in the global namespace. However, when they are wrapped inside a namespace, the compilation fails with

```
error: missing ‘target’ attribute for multi-versioned std::string nt::version()
```

I'm using GCC 4.8.2. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the functions in the nt namespace too.

```
//ver.cpp   
#include "ver.h"
namespace nt {
  __attribute__ ((target ("default"))) std::string version() { return "default"; } 
  __attribute__ ((target ("sse2")))    std::string version() { return "sse2";    } 
  __attribute__ ((target ("ssse3")))   std::string version() { return "ssse3";   } 
  __attribute__ ((target ("sse4")))    std::string version() { return "sse4";    }
}
```

Comment: They are. In the OPs question the functions are prefixed with `nt::`. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: It probably should, I don't quite see why gcc isn't able to parse that form - but it isn't..